# How to nest MULTISET in unnamed ROW in Informix?

Tags: sql, informix, multiset

Given this schema:

```sql
create table t (i int);
create table u (i int, j int);

insert into t values (1);
insert into t values (2);
insert into u values (1, 10);
insert into u values (2, 20);
```

The following query looks correct to me:

```sql
select
  t.i,
  row(
    multiset(
      select * from u where u.i = t.i
    )
  ) r
from t
order by t.i
```

But it produces some unspecified internal error:

> SQL Error [IX000]: User Defined Routine (collectionsend) execution failed.

Is this a documented limitation? How can I work around this problem? I'm using IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC5DE

Comment: Definitely a bug. In my case, your example crashed the Informix instance ( IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC5DE ) on linux ( CentOS Stream release 8 ).

Comment: Any Informix developer out there that could check if this bug is reported?

Comment: Curiously, it works if you drop the "order by" clause. Not that doing so presents a viable solution. I too was able to crash the server (14.10.FC7DE) with this. I will submit this to IBM.

Comment: IBM states that this will be fixed in 14.10.xC9. See also https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT40822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround might be to wrap the entire thing in a dummy `MULTISET` like this, which seems to work:

```sql
select multiset(
  select
    t.i,
    row(
      multiset(
        select * from u where u.i = t.i
      )
    ) r
  from t
  order by t.i
);
```

Though, when unnesting the auxiliary multiset again, the old error appears. This doesn't work:

```sql
select * from table(multiset(
  select
    t.i,
    row(
      multiset(
        select * from u where u.i = t.i
      )
    ) r
  from t
  order by t.i
)) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have verified that this is fixed in Informix 14.10.FC9

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT40822